# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment for loop

Tags: python

```
with open(r"C:\Users\rnd.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
def webhook():
    hook = { "content" = line }
    for line in lines:
        print(hook)
        time.sleep(30)
```

Output

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'line' referenced before assignment

Comment: What do you expect `hook = line` to do?

Comment: it was a dictionary hook = { "content" = line }

Comment: Yes, but what value do you think `hook` would have, since `line` isn't defined (and, for that matter, the syntax isn't correct; a dict display would be `{"content": line}`)?

Comment: Did you mean to use the (apparent) global variable `lines` instead?

Comment: @ZqdiacThanks `hook = { "content" = line }` is invalid syntax.  Again, what are you actually trying to do? You don't use `hook` anywhere, so just remove this for now.

Comment: i meant to do 
def webhook():
    hook = { "content" = line }
    for line in lines:
        print(hook)
        time.sleep(30)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `hook = line` because `line` is not yet defined at this point in your code. Since you never use `hook`, just remove this line to fix the error.

Comment: it was a dictionary 
hook = { "content" = line }